# Static fields and online games

Tags: java, sockets, static, static-members

Hello guys I have a little question about programming an online game: I was wondering if a static field is only shared by the local instances of a class or if it is shared by all the clients connected to the game server.

thank you!

Comment: Where is the `static` variable declared: in a class used in the client only or in a class used in your server only?

Comment: it's part of the game mechanics. I'm still working on the offline game and I was wondering if I could have problems using static fields when I'll put the game online.

Answer (score 5):

It's "local" to the `ClassLoader` which defines the class. It's unconnected to any *instances* of the class - for example, the variable can still be used even if there are *no* instances of the class. But it won't automatically be shared between different JVMs or even different ClassLoaders within the same JVM.